# Unique .txt file extension

Tags: python, text, format, rename

I have a python script that runs sub applications and open files that I want to have a special extension name. Currently the code is something like this:

```
file = print(open("/Users/admin/Desktop/%s.txt" % (input("Choose a file name: ")), 'w'))
file.close()
```

I assume that to get a unique extension the simplest way would be to rename the .txt format, but I have no idea how to do that. I have seen answers to this on Windows, but this is no help to me as I'm using Mac.

Comment: You want to change the filename (not extension) with a random and unique name? You could use a generated GUID.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the question. I was asking how to get a unique extension.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the unique filename you might use `tempfile`:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html